# LINQ-to-SQL .ExecuteCommand() doesn't work with parameterized object names

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I'm a little flummoxed by this one and hoping that someone can clarify what's going on.

I'd like to programmatically disable a foreign key constraint using my LINQ-to-SQL data context.  Seemingly this should be as easy as the following:

`context.ExecuteCommand( "ALTER TABLE {0} NOCHECK CONSTRAINT {1}", "MyTable", "FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable" );`

Unfortunately, this code bombs with the SQL error "Incorrect syntax near '@p0'."

When I fire up profiler I see that the SQL being generated is:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'ALTER TABLE @p0 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT @p1',
N'@p0 varchar(4000),@p1 varchar(4000)',
@p0=N'MyTable',
@p1=N'FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable'
```

From everything I can find in SQL Books Online and in the LINQ-to-SQL documentation this should just work.

I've resorted to doing this instead:

`context.ExecuteCommand( String.Format( "ALTER TABLE {0} NOCHECK CONSTRAINT {1}", "MyTable", "FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable" ) );`

It works, but it sort of defeats the purpose of being able to pass in parameters to .ExecuteCommand().

So is this some kind of quirk in LINQ-to-SQL, SQL Server or am I just really confused?

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've found out - Linq-to-SQL will quite aggressively try to parametrize your queries. Which is a *good thing*, in most cases.

But in the case of an `ALTER TABLE...` statement, things like the table name etc. **cannot** be parametrized - so therefore, it fails.

I don't know if there's any way of getting Linq-to-SQL to *not* parametrize certain queries to be executed by `ExecuteCommand` - for the meantime, I think, statements that don't involve manipulating data (inserting, updating etc.) but rather manipulate the structure of your database, your best bet is to use the `String.Format(...)` approach to get the actual SQL query as a string, before calling `.ExecuteCommand()`.

Comment: Thanks for the very concise explanation.  Much appreciated.

Comment: ALTER TABLE is a Data Definition Language (DDL) type statement. So I think its reasonable that LINQ falls down here. I don't see any claims that LINQ is a DDL tool.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use SQL objects as parameters.

So the second version is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL is basically just translating what you have given it.  The problem is that you can't have table names as parameters so the following does not work.

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar

SET @Tablename='MyTable'

SELECT * FROM @TableName
```

It looks like you already have a solution, and I think it's a good one.

Comment: Makes sense.  And, of course, LINQ-to-SQL has no way of knowing that my parameters are object names.